# Open images at multiple coordinates Python 3.9

Tags: python, image, import

so I am very new and just trying to change where these images show up on the screen. Since they all currently pop up at the same spot, its kind of useless

```
import os

os.system("pic.jpeg")
os.system("pic.jpeg")
os.system("pic.jpeg")
os.system("pic.jpeg")
```

Comment: what is your operating system?

Comment: Heads up that if you want to position images to *compose* some larger image, draw things, or even create a GUI, then ``os.system`` is the wrong approach. Use a library such as ``tkinter``, ``pygame``, etc that puts the display entirely under your control.

Comment: If you're using `os.system()`, your default program for opening `jpg` files will open that image, and it's not possible to sent parameters to the program since you're not calling it directly. You'd have to explicitly call the specific program you want to use to display the image, and that program would also have to be able to accept command line arguments that allow the image to be displayed at specific coordinates. That's OS and program specific, so the code wouldn't be universal. By using a Python library instead, like `tkinter` or `pygame` for example, you'd have full control on any OS.

Comment: @DavidKaftan win10

Comment: @MisterMiyagi got it thank you